# Localized WiFi problems in Windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I live in a large apartment complex with hundreds of APs broadcasting a single network. I also have my own cheap Netgear AP broadcasting my own private network.

I frequently have issues with my WiFi connections at home, but never anywhere else. The problems began after I installed Windows 10, so I think it might be a driver or configuration issue, and I need help figuring it out.

The best way to demonstrate my problem is `ping google.com`. When things are bad, 50% of packets will time out. When things are really bad, the DNS resolution of `google.com` will time out. I've already had the apartment replace the AP that serves my apartment, which has only done a little to help.

I use a Lenovo Thinkpad T530 with Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2200 and Windows 10 Pro x64. When looking at the properties for my wireless chipset, I see the following driver file details:

```
NETwew00.sys    Intel Corporation        15.12.0.9
Netwfw00.dat    Unknown                  Unknown
vwifibus.sys    Microsoft Corporation    10.0.10240.16384 (th 1.150709-1700)
```

Can anyone please help me troubleshoot? I just set `Roaming Aggressiveness` to `Highest`, hopefully that will improve things in the short term. (Also, does anyone know what the new message "Checking network requirements" means?)

Comment: Your problem statement is not very clear. Which network are you troubling with? The apartment network or your private network? How are the two networks linked? Are you connected to your private network and then trying to access the internet via the apartment connection or does your private netwotk have its own separate internet connection?

Comment: You are trying to find causation in two unrelated events.  You having problems with network noise which causes a disconnection after upgrading to Windows 10 and the continued problem of that said network noise.  The simplest solution is to migrated to the 5.0 GHz band and avoid the noise all together.  The ` Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2200` is notorious for having problems like this by the way and have **nothing** to do with with Windows 10.